# what's the difference between import "name" from "module" and import * as "name" from "module"?

Tags: javascript, javascript-import

The code on my app is like this.

```js
import { HttpExceptionFilter } from './common/exceptions/http-exception.filter';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DocumentBuilder, OpenAPIObject, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';
//1.
import * as expressBasicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';
//2. 
//import expressBasicAuth from 'express-basic-auth'; => promise unhandled error

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe()); 
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());

  app.use(
    ['/docs', '/docs-json'],
    expressBasicAuth({
      challenge: true,
      users: {
        [process.env.SWAGGER_USER]: process.env.SWAGGER_PASSWORD,
      },
    }),
  );
};
```

I want to know the difference between 1 and 2.

Because When I run my app using 2(9 lines), there was promise unhandled error.

I want to know how those two ways work. I referred to the official document of mozilla, but I couldn't understand it well.
I'd appreciate it if you could answer me.

Answer (score 3):

First let's just understand how imports works

so consider i have a file with the following exports

```js
// file name -> modules
export const add = (x, y) => x + y;
export const subtract = (x, y) => x - y;
export default (x, y) => x * y;
```

now i can import all these functions on another file like this

```js
import defaultFunction, { add, subtract } from './modules.js';

console.log(add(1, 2)) // 3
console.log(subtract(2, 1)) // 1
console.log(defaultFunction(2, 2)) // 2 * 2 = 4
```

or i can use `import * as <name> from <file/package>` to import all the exports inside a file.

like this

```js
import * as myModules from './modules.js';
// NOTE: this will only give you add and subtract functions but not the default one
// now to actually access the default function you have to use
// import * as <name> from <file/package>
// <name>.default to access the default export
// or simply
// import default, { } from <file/package>


console.log(myModules.add(1, 2)) // 3
console.log(myModules.subtract(2, 1)) // 1
console.log(myModules.default(2, 2)) // 2 * 2 = 4

// or i can destructure the "myModules" import

const { add, subtract } = myModules;
```

**Conclusion**

I think the problem is that the library that you're using is not providing a default export to actually use `import expressBasicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';` or it might be exporting different functions for `named exports` and `default exports`

Comment: Thank you for explaining.
I perfectly understood.

Comment: np please consider marking it as a correct answer if it helped you :D

Answer (score 1):

As per your code:

1. `import * as expressBasicAuth from ...`

   Imports all `export const variable1...; export const variable2...;` items as a single item.
2. `import expressBasicAuth from ...`

   Imports a single `export default` item if there was one defined inside the library.

Depending on the library implementation, there might be totally different functions exported in those two ways.

Comment: I understood more easily because of your simple explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the module exports multiple things
There are two great ways to import from another module when the module exports an object with properties. This is the common case.

Import the whole module, giving it a name:

```
import * as child_process from "child_process";

// then later...
child_process.spawn(...);
or pick the names you want to import:

import { spawn } from "child_process";

// then later
spawn(...);
```

sometimes the module exports just one thing. typescript has the concept of export default
If a module declares a default export, then you must bring it in like this:

```
import thing from "thing";
```

Now you have a function or a class (whatever its default export is) in the thing.

More commonly in JavaScript (CommonJS?) modules, a module author will override `module.exports` to a function or class instead of adding properties to the exports object like a ES-module would.

so in common js we have

```
const expressBasicAuth = require(express-basic-auth);
```

and in typescript :

```
import * as expressBasicAuth from 'express-basic-auth';
```

Comment: Thank you for your further explanation. I could understand it from a different angle.